# symfony3 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO

Tags: php, symfony

Entity:

```
class User
{
  /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
  private $id;
...
```

But I tried to change IDENTITY to AUTO and the same.

Form:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
    ->add('email',EmailType::class, array('label'=>'E-mail'))
    ->add('login',TextType::class, array('label'=>'Login'))
    ->add('password',PasswordType::class, array('label'=>'Hasło'))
    ->add('name',TextType::class, array('label'=>'Imię'))
    ->add('surname',TextType::class, array('label'=>'Nazwisko'))
    ->add('Zarejestruj',SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Zarejestruj'));
  }
```

Controller:

```
   $user = new User();
   $form=$this->createForm(Register::class, $user);
   $form->handleRequest($request);

   if ($form->isValid())
   {
     $data=$request->request->all();
     $username=$data['register']['login'];
     $password=$data['register']['password'];
     $email=$data['register']['email'];
     $name=$data['register']['name'];
     $surname=$data['register']['surname'];

     $user=new User();
     $user->setLogin($username);
     $user->setPassword($password);
     $user->setEmail($email);
     $user->setName($name);
     $user->setSurname($surname);

     $add=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $add->persist($user);
     $add->flush();
    ...
```

And I still have error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (login, password, email, name, surname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["test2", "test2", "Taylor", "David", null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'surname' cannot be null
```

I did that in symofny 3.1.4 and it worked, but now I use symfony 3.1.5 and now I have this problem...

Comment: `* @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)` you set nullable to false and the error is throw from database - make column allow null on database and set `nullable=true`

Comment: Why do you assign data to `User` **manually** if you're calling `handleRequest`? :) Other than that, here is the change log for 3.1.5 https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-1-5-released. Glancing over quickly, don't see anything related to your issue.

Comment: @JovanPerovic You are my hero now! I didn't know, that I can add this from handleRequest! Now is so short code, awesome. And You had right, it's not wrong about symfony 3.1.5, I had mistake too in Entity. Thanks very much for help.